# Outgrew google sheets but do not have expertise in SQL. Is there an interim solution?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Our nonprofit uses google sheets to transform data. The first file has the raw data, which comes to us in a CSV. Data gets passed from one file to another with =importrange. Intermediate files transform various parts of it with lot of google sheet formulas such as =split, =vlookup, =if, =textjoin, =concatenate, etc. The final file has the data in the form that we can use to create pages in our website.

The first file has about 150 columns. The new 10M cell limit should let us get about 60k rows, but even that number freezes up, and we need to get up into the millions of rows. All of the transformer files, together, add up to about 3k columns.

We assume that the ultimate solution is to re-create it all in a SQL database, but we do not have any expertise of that type, nor the funding to hire someone.

- Is there an easy way to transform a google sheet (with formulas) into
  a SQL file?
- Is there an easy interim solution, which we can use for a
  while?

Comment: perhaps see: https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/

Comment: In regards to your first question (transform a google sheet into a sql file), what do you mean? What do you mean by "sql file"?

Comment: Keep in mind that while you know your current "system," we do not. So it's difficult to make suggestions, or for you to understand those that might be made. But it seems to me that Google Sheets can handle plenty of data, just perhaps not the way you are processing it. For instance, incoming data could be routed to various separate spreadsheets alphabetically (or numerically) by grouping. Sub-spreadsheets could process. Other sub-spreadsheets could collect the processed data. An end spreadsheet could work as a hub to access penultimate spreadsheets as required.

Comment: The above is something I've done many, many times with clients. And it all works automatically with no lag. As to someone who would donate that kind of time.... all I can say is that it is a *lot of time*. There are no free, easy solutions to do a complex, customized task.